# Download zipped CSV file on client side using Java and struts2 

Tags: java, struts2

How can I download a zipped CSV file on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

In your Struts Action you need to set the appropriate response headers and then send the file.

```
  response.setContentType("application/zip");
  response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", 
       "attachment; filename=file.csv.zip");
  IOUtils.copy(zippedCsvFile, response.getOutputStream());
```

Doing the zip compression on the fly is also an option, as is generating the whole file, of course. If so, you may want to look at DeflaterOutputStream and [some library to write CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053761/what-is-a-good-csv-java-utility).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [tutorial](http://sheetalshundori.blogspot.com/2008/02/struts2-dynamic-file-download.html) on how to download dynamic file using Struts2.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I have tried this but i am not able to download zipped csv file